# Emulating ARM environment using QEMU

Tags: virtualization, arm, qemu

I am trying to emulate ARM architecture using QEMU. My host OS is ubuntu 16.04 and the guest OS inside the emulated machine is also ubuntu 16.04. Hardware specifications of my host system are:

Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4

Memory: 7.7 GiB

OS-type: 64 bit

Disk 976.0 GB

Following is the tutorial that I'm following:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm qemu-efi

dd if=/dev/zero of=flash0.img bs=1M count=64
dd if=/usr/share/qemu-efi/QEMU_EFI.fd of=flash0.img conv=notrunc
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash1.img bs=1M count=64

sudo qemu-system-arm -m 1024 -cpu cortex-a15 -M virt -nographic -drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive if=none,file=xenial-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img,id=hd0 -netdev user,id=net0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=$(printf 'DE:AD:BE:EF:%02X:%02X\n' $((RANDOM%256)) $((RANDOM%256)))
```

This is resulting into terminal getting stuck. I have tried it multiple times and left it for almost 30 min but nothing appears on the screen. The cursor blinks a few times and then that's it. Closing the terminal displays a dialogue box that says,

```
    "There is still a process running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it."
```

This is the first time I'm emulating a machine in QEMU. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With `-nographic` you will see nothing - qemu has to open its own window. This parameter should only be used when there is another way to reach the virtual machine. Documentation is [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor).

Comment: @ridgy I have tried removing the '-nographic' option as well. It just opens the blank QEMU monitor with just a cursor blinking and nothing else happens.  I think if the emulation is running, it should show on the QEMU monitor as well, no?

Comment: I never used `qemu-system-arm`; maybe you'ld have to define additional boot order/bootmenu parameter.Or try just with one drive (the one to boot from).